# Why PowerShell treats slash in DateTime format string as dot?

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\> (Get-Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
11.12.2016

PS C:\> [DateTime]::ParseExact('10/14/2016', 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null)
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."At line:1 char:1
+ [DateTime]::ParseExact('10/14/2016', 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException


PS C:\> [DateTime]::ParseExact('10.14.2016', 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null)

14 Oct 2016 0:00:00



PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117
```

It is on Windows Server 2008 R2.
On Windows 10 version is 5.1.14393.206 and it works correctly.

What is going on?

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4), in particular the section "the '/' custom format specifier". You don't want to specify `$null` for the third argument if you want predictable results across locales.

Comment: @JeroenMostert hey, I can't accept an answer when it is a comment :)

Comment: My comment is only a very lazy beginning of an answer, so that's by design. :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert well, that's enough. Thank you anyways, I was blaming usual PS weirdness to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566528/why-powershell-treats-slash-in-datetime-format-string-as-dot#comment68369975_40566528) pointed out in the comments to your question, the forward slash has a special meaning in date/time format strings.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator):

> ### The "/" custom format specifier
>
> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate localized date separator is retrieved from the `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property of the current or specified culture.
>
> > **Note**
> >     To change the date separator for a particular date and time string, specify the separator character within a literal string delimiter. For example, the custom format string `mm'/'dd'/'yyyy` produces a result string in which "/" is always used as the date separator. To change the date separator for all dates for a culture, either change the value of the `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property of the current culture, or instantiate a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object, assign the character to its `DateSeparator` property, and call an overload of the formatting method that includes an `IFormatProvider` parameter.

For matching a literal forward slash instead of the date separator defined in the system's regional settings escape it with a backslash (`'MM\/dd\/yyyy'`).

Also, passing `$null` for the format provider is not recommended. Either specify the correct [culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) for the date string, or use [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) if you want the string parsed independent of a particular culture.

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('10/14/2016', 'MM\/dd\/yyyy', [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `InvariantCulture` if you have a non-localized value to handle.

```
PS C:\> ([Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture).DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator
/
```

On my system, I have the date format set for ISO-8601. That causes my separator to be a hyphen `-`.

```
PS C:\> (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator
-
```

Interesting conversion.

```
PS C:\> (Get-Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
11-12-2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Long form:

```
Get-Date -Format "yyyy\/MM\/dd"
```

Short-hand:

```
date -f "yyyy\/MM\/dd"
```

Note that, yes, in this instance, you use backslashes as the escape character, instead of tildes.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this :

```
get-date -format "yyyy/MM/dd"
```